# Need Help - Dynamic Click EventHandler with custom arguments - Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, event-handling

I am attempting to dynamically create a custom event handler with custom arguments passed through.  Basically, I have a panel with a click event added:

```
Panel awardButton = new Panel();
awardButton.Click += new EventHandler(PreviewAward);
```

I want to send a few variables to my PreviewAward function.  I tried everything I know but get nothing but errors.  I tried searching for help and this is the closest I could find:

[EventHandler with custom arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457474/c-sharp-eventhandler-with-custom-arguments)

I tried using that code as follows:

```
awardButton.Click += (sender, e) => PreviewAward(dtAward.Rows[0]["iconImage"].ToString());
```

Everything on the right side of the lambda is underlined in red saying "No overload for method 'PreviewAward' takes 1 argument".  I guess I am not understanding how the lambda works because I thought the (sender, e) was being passed into the PreviewAward method along with my "iconImage" string making 3 arguments total, not one.  Also, I tried adding the variable to my method but get the same error.  Here is the method:

```
    private void PreviewAward(object sender, EventArgs e, string slot)
    {
        string str = ((Panel)sender).Name;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Utils.StrToByteArray(str));
        MemoryStream preview = new MemoryStream(Utils.ImageMerge(((System.Drawing.Image)(Avatar.Properties.Resources.resizeButtonIn)), Image.FromStream(ms), 200, 200));
        Debug.Print("Show Preview for item: " + str);
    }
```

When I mouse-over the function on the right side of the lambda, I get the little drop-down on 'PreviewAward' that wants me to create a method stub.  If I click that, it creates this:

```
    private object PreviewAward(string p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I have no idea what to do with that, especially being that it doesn't have my 'sender' in it.  I was under the impression that it would use the 'private void PreviewAward' method that I already created instead of making me create a new 'private object' method of the same name... I am thoroughly confused!  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have a "solution" but I really want to learn this lambda expression stuff!  So, I am still looking for an answer to this, however, here is my solution:

I created a custom class and added all the variables I want to pass:

    class MyPanel : System.Windows.Controls.Panel
    {
        public int id;
        public string imgString;
    }

Use EventHandler as normal:

awardButton.Click += new EventHandler(PreviewAward);

In my PreviewAward method:

string str = ((Panel)sender).Name;
int id = ((Panel)sender).id;
string imgStr = ((Panel)sender).imgString;

Comment: Correction:
System.Windows.Controls.Panel = System.Windows.Forms.Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (sender, e) parameters aren't being passed to your PreviewAward method automatically.

They are being passed to your lambda, and in your lambda you are simply not using them, and manually calling PreviewAward with a single string parameter.

There are a few ways you could fix this, but the simplest is just to modify your lambda a bit so that it passes in the required arguments to the PreviewAward method.

```
awardButton.Click += (sender, e) => PreviewAward(sender, e, dtAward.Rows[0]["iconImage"].ToString());
```

Edit: That said, it's a bit of a strange design to have a click event handler that requires an extra parameter - it means that the signature of the method doesn't match the EventHandler signature. It might be worth rethinking the design a bit so that the third parameter is calculated inside of the method, for example.